# Golang single page website server

Tags: reactjs, go, react-router, single-page-application

I'm trying to build some spa/spw with golang and react-router as the back-end, but I've encountered a little problem.

React-router seems to base itself around the idea that any "bad" request to the server (e.g. /path/dynamicRessourceHash ) delivers an .html page the user (said html page then imports the .js from the server) and react-router then kicks in, analyzes the path and gives the application the information needed to make fetch requests in the background and deliver the resources to the user.

So what would be the standard way to configure a server like this using "net/http" from std , that is, to server resources normally on pre-configured endpoints but treat all other endpoints as wildcards for one (or few) routes ?

Just to give an example (since today I seem to be bad with words). Say the user makes a request at:

/route1/whatever/someotherstuff?... etc whatever the things after the second "/" are I want the user to be served by the handler function for /route1/ (Note, i don't want the user to be redirected, since that fucks up the URL and consequently the client-side routing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `net/http` you can use the handler than serves the `/` route to return a 404 page since all unknown / unregistered routes match `/`.

```
http.HandleFunc("/", handler)

...

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
       w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
       // Write custom 404 Page to w.Write()
        return
    }
    // Handling for route /
}
```

You could also use a different http multiplexer that supports `Not Found Handlers`.

Eg.

In [`httprouter`](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) you set [`httprouter.Router.NotFound`](https://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#Router)

OR

In [`gorilla/mux`](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) you set [`mix.Router.NotFoundHandler`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Router)

Comment: "since all unknown / unregistered routes match /" ... I have no idea why I didn't knew this o.o, seemed like the kind of thing I should have learned way, way,way back.

Comment: `Note that since a pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree, the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered patterns, not just the URL with Path == "/".` from [GoDoc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux)